# How to consolidate differently structured CSV files into one with Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am facing the following challenge:

I have 300 different CSV files in my Python project directory, all with a different structure, i.e. different columns, and want to combine all of these files into one single consolidated CSV file.

Let me give a 2 file example:

marketcap.csv:

```
marketcap,ticker
1000,AAPL
2000,TSLA
3000,OSTK
```

revenue.csv:

```
revenue,ticker
2000,AAPL
300,MDXG
```

The consolidated csv file should be structured as follows:

consolidated.csv:

```
marketcap,revenue,ticker
1000,2000,AAPL
2000,0,TSLA
3000,0,OSTK
0,300,MDXG
```

I have a complete list of 300 different columns (all known) and there are 300 resulting CSV files. The tickers are not known in advance. As you can see from the example above, the available tickers in each file can vary, i.e. if a ticker isn't listed in one file it should automatically get a 0 for the respective datapoint, e.g. revenue, in the consolidated file.

I have searched stackoverflow but didn't find this specific question answered. Thanks for your help and ideas about how to solve this.

Comment: Do all the files have a common column? would that be 'ticker'? 

Knowing a common column will make it a lot easier.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured a way to find the common columns while reading the files. I'll update my answer. 

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the current sample, a one-liner using pandas dataframe works very well. You'll need to provide the common columns for each file to see how it works for those 300 files.

## For Smaller dataset

When you know the common Columns in the files:

```
# Create dataframes from csv:
market = pd.read_csv("filepath/market.csv")filepath/market.csv")
revenue = pd.read_csv("filepath/revenue.csv")

# Merge both files using pd.merge
consolidated = market.merge(revenue,how='outer', on='ticker').fillna(value=0)
# This gives a full merge of both csv and fillna replaces null values with '0'
```

## Updated code for 300 files

This piece of code searches for the common columns in the two dataframes before merge.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

directory = 'C:/Test' # specify the directory containing the 300 files
filelist = sorted (glob.glob(directory + '/*.csv')) # reads all 300 files in the directory and stores as a list
consolidated = pd.DataFrame() # Create a new empty dataframe for consolidation
for file in filelist:            # Iterate through each of the 300 files
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file)      # create df using the file  
    df1col = list (df1.columns)  # save columns to a list
    df2 = consolidated           # set the consolidated as your df2
    df2col = list (df2.columns)  # save columns from consolidated result as list
    commoncol = [i for i in df1col for j in df2col if i==j] # Check both lists for common column name
    # print (commoncol)
    if commoncol == []:          # In first iteration, consolidated file is empty, which will return in a blank df
        consolidated = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).fillna(value=0)  # concatenate (outer join) with no common columns replacing null values with 0
    else:
        consolidated = df1.merge(df2,how='outer', on=commoncol).fillna(value=0)        # merge both df specifying the common column and replace null values with 0
    # print (consolidated)   << Optionally, check the consolidated df at each iteration 

# writing consolidated df to another CSV
consolidated.to_csv('C:/<filepath>/consolidated.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: I realized that there might be cases when on of the files doesn't match with any existing column in Consolidated. Have updated the code to cover that. 

This is done by using pd.concat which performs a default outer join on all columns.

Comment: Hi, I used the code and get the following error message: "  File "/Users/xxxxx/PycharmProjects/csv-download/CSV-Consolidate.py", line 7
    consolidated = pd.DataFrame() # Create a new empty dataframe for consolidation
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Process finished with exit code 1"


Line 7 contains: 
consolidated = pd.DataFrame()

Comment: I had missed the import pandas command.Added it now. Please check again.

Comment: I added it and the error message remains the same. The right hand side remark in PyCharm in line 2 where I added the import pandas statement says "unused import statement". I have installed pandas via pip.

Comment: Usually when python gives a syntax error, it has something to do with your previous line. Can you try to figure that out? I know the issue ;)

Comment: Hi Parv, I am a newcomer to Python so I appreciate your guidance, thanks for your help.

Comment: Alright, I was hoping you'd try.  There was a closing bracket ')' missing in the 'glob' line 6. Added it now.

Comment: Ah yes, this was the issue, thanks! How do I write the resulting "consolidated" content back into a file called consolidated.csv?

Comment: So, I guess the code worked?  I should have added the export to csv option in my original code. Done now.

Comment: Thank you very much Parv for all help and the great code, it works like a charm. Appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks! Glad it worked :) And I hope you've learned from the code.